# Mobile CSS3 animation dont work

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a webfont icon here: http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/mobile/artistchannel.php

See the heart in the blue box just below the image. When checking on CanIUse.com I can see CSS3 Animations are possible, but when testing in mobile Chrome and Dolphin this doesn't work. In desktop it seems to work. What could be wrong?

Comment: did you check your vendor prefixes?

Comment: Yeah. Both -Webkit and non-webkit is added.